# Easiest way to silence "word is too long to be indexed" notices in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, tsvector

I have some SQL statements that cause this to happen:

```
NOTICE:  word is too long to be indexed
DETAIL:  Words longer than 2047 characters are ignored.
```

What's the easiest way to not have these notices be generated in the first place?  (It's a long story why I'd want to do it that way.)

An example of such a statement is this:

```
update rev set html = regexp_replace(html,
                         '***=<a href="' || old.url || '">',
                         '<a href="' || new.url || '">',
                         'gi')
        where id in (
            select id
                    from rev
                    where to_tsvector('tags_only', html) @@
                      plainto_tsquery('tags_only','<a href="' || old.url || '">')
        )
```

It's not the A tags with long urls or anything causing the problem.  It's probably embedded CDATA-style graphics.  I don't care that they're not indexed, whatever they are.  I just want these notices to not occur.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind suppressing all notices just change PostgreSQL error reporting level. `client_min_messages` defines lowest level of error/warning/notice messages sent to client, `log_min_messages` does the same for messages saved in log. Possible values are: `DEBUG5, DEBUG4, DEBUG3, DEBUG2, DEBUG1, INFO, NOTICE, WARNING, ERROR, LOG, FATAL, PANIC`

edit:

Disable for this query only: `SET LOCAL client_min_messages TO WARNING;`

Disable for this session only: `SET SESSION client_min_messages TO WARNING;`

Disable for this user: `ALTER ROLE username SET client_min_messages TO WARNING;`